# Truffle migrate stuck at first migration

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

i am running a private Quorum node, which is basically normal ethereum node, via geth.

Then i tried to do deploy contract using migrate from truffle. but it got stuck here :

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0xbe63f4d73fa716a96b3e91792b24e789598978c7e93f396f0898e27dfb651c2a
```

this is my geth "command" :
`qgeth --rpc --rpcport 22000` (qgeth is justan alias for quorum geth)

and this is the output of the terminal i am running the geth on

```
NFO [03-05|16:55:51] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable-df4267a2/linux-amd64/go1.10
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/user/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: <nil> Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: <nil> EIP158: <nil> Byzantium: <nil> IsQuorum: true Engine: unknown}"
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/user/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/user/.ethash               count=2
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=9ff7ff…ad72b2 td=0
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=9ff7ff…ad72b2 td=0
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=9ff7ff…ad72b2 td=0
WARN [03-05|16:55:51] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [03-05|16:55:51] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=2 dropped=0
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=2 accounts=1
INFO [03-05|16:55:51] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [03-05|16:55:53] UDP listener up                          self=enode://5f7a8e81143054d8aecdfcc6a93b6d2d2a8fe0300a48a35af6dadab6cf364da9a5ea0e2dc8b75239f01a9e1cea22f6529a8308cdf447adaa2fe4e674aa3c580c@[::]:30303
INFO [03-05|16:55:53] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://5f7a8e81143054d8aecdfcc6a93b6d2d2a8fe0300a48a35af6dadab6cf364da9a5ea0e2dc8b75239f01a9e1cea22f6529a8308cdf447adaa2fe4e674aa3c580c@[::]:30303
INFO [03-05|16:55:53] IPC endpoint opened: /home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc 
INFO [03-05|16:55:53] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:22000 
INFO [03-05|17:00:01] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0x78b4cf12fc34b32ea4d174fa2bb4d8fba5e4c018722105eb5453fc8fc0979776 to=0xA8879FfBe2f4bAea1b37D00Bb2EFF38629B94EF4
INFO [03-05|17:01:21] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0x24f4ea4dd9f3a41bfd019381c2d630fa63a9f365615397932bf9db5c450c4c22 to=0x18EBcB24F6074147DF24C39df3b833288b0e686b
INFO [03-05|17:01:46] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0xbe63f4d73fa716a96b3e91792b24e789598978c7e93f396f0898e27dfb651c2a to=0x7D8e4ea6319e950c5400A60ab18f305bAcAA2F12
WARN [03-05|17:06:30] System clock seems off by -72h0m7.633984816s, which can prevent network connectivity 
WARN [03-05|17:06:30] Please enable network time synchronisation in system settings.
```

Why would this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Your node seems to have a 3 days delay with the rest of the network. Check the date of your node as a node with delay cannot communicate with the network.

Try this to enable NTP on Ubuntu:
`timedatectl set-ntp true`

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo service ntp start
```

Comment: I fixed the time problem, restarted the node. Nothing happens. it is not about the time

Comment: I had the same issue with Quorum.I had solved this issue by doing the same migrate command in one more terminal.btw I am still searching the reason for it

Comment: The time certainly was a problem, too. Can you post the recent geth locs after fixing the time issue ? (use pastebin or the like)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I fixed it by updating my Ethereum node to the latest version.